# Push notfication from Visual studio Appcenter

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to get push notification to work from appcenter, I followed the tutorial from the docs and James on Channel 9, and I noticed notification are only getting delivered if I send them directly from Google Firebase, if I push from appcenter nothing shows up.  Any idea

Comment: Can you check if you have followed all steps in the docs: [push/android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/android) and [push/service-config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/service-config).

Answer (score 1):

Under the authentication section in firebase add the appcentercom url to Authorized domains
That wasnt mentioned in the article.

[image]